# Does a subroutine called by a function have to finish for the function to proceed?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, function, subroutine

If a subroutine is called within a function, does the function always wait until that subroutine is completely finished before it will proceed with the rest of the function?  If so, is there any way to make it not wait and continue on with the rest of function and not care what happens in the subroutine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the normal course of things yes, the calls are synchronous. That is, when you make a call to a subroutine from a function, the subroutine will fully execute and only when finished will execution resume in the calling function.

You need to use asynchronous programming to achieve what you want.

See [Calling Synchronous Methods Asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx) on MSDN for details.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is 'asynchronous method call', which leads to very broad question 'how to run method asynchronously'. And the answer depends on the requirements.

You might want to start from here: [Asynchronous Programming Design Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should asynchronously call your subroutine by using BeginInvoke. Check out this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=VS.100).aspx